# Empty Table of contents even after multiple compilations

Tags: table-of-contents

I am very new to Latex

and Cant figure this out

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=1.5in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    right=1in,
    }
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Topic}
\lfoot{Institute Name, Branch}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{document}

%FRONT PAGE
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
A project Report on\\
\vspace{0.5in}
{\textbf{ \Huge Topic}}\\
\vspace{0.5in}
By\\
\vspace{0.3in}
{\textbf{\large Name1\\Name2\\Name3}}\\
\vspace{0.5in}
Guide\\
\vspace{0.3in}
{\textbf{\large Professor Name}}\\
\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{institute_logo.png}\\
\vspace{0.5in}
{\Large Department \\
Institute Name\\
2020-21\\}
\end{center}


\chapter*{Certificate}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\tableofcontents


\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}


\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Literature Review}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Design and Drawings}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Analysis}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\thispagestyle{fancy}



\end{document}
```

Table of contents is empty after compiling multiple times

Comment: By default, unnumbered (aka starred) chapters and sections don't go into the table of contents.  What is your intention in not numbering?  Do you want them to appear anyway?

Comment: I want to hide the chapter number in the heading

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're going about getting unnumbered chapters wrong. `\chapter*` is really only meant to be used as part of other commands (like `\tableofcontents`) for printing chapter-like headings without generating table of contents entries or modifying page headers.¹

To get unnumbered chapters, instead, use normal `\chapter` commands throughout and instead put the following in your table of contents:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

This will cause everything except for `\part` commands to be unnumbered. You're not using `\part` so it shouldn't matter that the parts are numbered. If you wanted unnumbered parts, you could change `-1` to `-2` above.

---

1. Personally, I think that `\chapter*` et al were an ill-advised addition to LaTeX and one that should not have been exposed in user-accessible format in any event, but that ship has sailed.

Comment: I didnt want "Chapter 1 Abstract" like heading, just "Abstract". So, Chapter*{} did the trick but then it doesnt show up on table of contents because its now unnumbered.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me :

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code
```

and I am using chapter{} instead of chapter*{} now

so my chapters are numbered and instead of "Chapter 1 Abstract" now its "Abstract"
which is exactly what I wanted. Should have clarified this while asking :p